# Downloading of blockchain failed

Tags: client, blockchain, wallet, installation

I’ve been attempting to set up my own wallet, but am having difficulties.  Last week I began installing the standard Bitcoin client.
When I first attempted I got to the process of downloading the blockchain.  My computer ran for about 36 hours until the process failed.  I asked on the message boards and they said there may have been some corrupted data.  I attempted to re download the blockchain, but when I reinstall Bitcoin, I now get a failed to initialize message.  I deleted the original files (except the wallet file) and still get a failed message when Bitcoin starts.  It's getting pretty frustrating.  I sent 1 bitcoin to the first address I created (though it had not yet and never did finish downloading the block chain).  Would deleting the wallet allow me to start over?

Comment: Operating system & Version?  Also, assuming this is the Bitcoin.org client, which version?

This wouldn't be a permissions issue, by chance?

Answer (score 1):

If you sent a coin there, of course you need to keep the wallet itself or you won't be able to claim that coin.

You may delete and re-download the blockchain, though.

Or you can try to open the wallet with another client.

Comment: I have attempted that several times.  I've put the wallet on a flash drive and unistalled bitcoin all together.  I've restarted my computer and done a program search to confirm that there are not bitcoin programs on my computer.  However once the wallet begins to run after about 10 seconds (before the blocking process begins) I get the following message "error loading blkindex.dat"

Comment: I've no idea what the "blocking process" is. Are you sure you sent bitcoins to that wallet? How did you do that?

Comment: When I first downloaded the program it began downloading the block chain.  I let it run for 36 hours, at which point it failed.  I was told it would need to complete the chain one time, however after it failed no subsiquent attempts to open a wallet have succeded.  Once you get to the point where it says "completing the bitcoin setup window" and press finish I see the wallet icon saying "loading block index" and after about 10 seconds a "error loading blkindex.dat" message after which the program closes